# tmap : separate the legend + add logos below the map box

Tags: r, mapping, legend, tmap, graphical-logo

I have two different questions regarding the `tmap` package.

1. Is it possible to put a legend on the right side of the map and another on the left part? I have a point symbology with two possible different colors, and in each point there is a different number (n=26). I would like to have the color definition on the left side and the list of numbers with each number definition on the right side of the map...
2. I would like to add the logos of all the organisations that have contributed to the data collection. But when I use the function `tm_logo`, the logos (png) fall inside the bbox so over the map. I would like to have them below the map, outside the box...

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: I have done similar customized maps using `ggdraw` of the `cowplot` package. You might need to save each element into a different object, use `tmap_grob` to transform them into `grobs` and then play with its position in `ggdraw`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I have indeed managed to add the logos with ggdraw quite easily.  
It's a shame we can't separate the legend easily with tmap...

Comment: You can use `tm_layout(legend.only = T)` to save only the legend.

Comment: Sorry I meant separate the legend in two parts, for ex in two columns. As you can see here https://www.kora.ch/fr/especes/loup/distribution#d1b981ae6d52de14f7fab044f13f65f9-2 
the legend is already very long, and I would like to separate it in two columns or put one part to the left side of the map and the other part to the right side of the map...